# How to set a file path?

Tags: excel, vba, path

What I'm trying to do is to copy/paste a selected report. How to add default path when the select menu pops up?

```
Sub PopulateUploaderFunds()
Dim uploadfile As Variant
Dim uploader As Workbook
Dim CurrentBook As Workbook

Set CurrentBook = ActiveWorkbook
MsgBox ("Please select uploader file to be reviewed")
uploadfile = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    If uploadfile = "False" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Workbooks.Open uploadfile
Set uploader = ActiveWorkbook
With uploader
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy
    uploader.Close
End With

CurrentBook.Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below worked for me after testing. Big thanks to @Damian. I combined his code with mine, the result is what I exactly wanted.

```
    Sub PopulateUploaderFunds()
Dim uploadfile As Variant
Dim uploader As Workbook
Dim CurrentBook As Workbook

Set CurrentBook = ActiveWorkbook
MsgBox ("Please select uploader file to be reviewed")
    uploadfile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .InitialFileName = "" 'here place your path
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Add "Custom Excel Files", "*.csv, *.xlsx, *.xls, *.txt"
        If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub  ' if Cancel is pressed
        uploadfile = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Workbooks.Open uploadfile
Set uploader = ActiveWorkbook
With uploader
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy
    uploader.Close
End With

CurrentBook.Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I did change a bit your code, and I'm pretty sure your code couldn't work. You copied from the uploader workbook correctly, but then you close it and try to paste into the currentworkbook. If you close the workbook while copying, there will be nothing to paste.

```
Option Explicit
Sub PopulateUploaderFunds()

    Dim uploadfile As String 'not variant
    Dim uploader As Workbook
    Dim CurrentBook As Workbook

    MsgBox ("Please select uploader file to be reviewed")
    uploadfile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .InitialFileName = "C:\" 'here you change the path
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Add "CSV", "*.csv"
        If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub  ' if Cancel is pressed
        uploadfile = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With

    Set CurrentBook = ThisWorkbook 'ActiveWorkbook would throw errors, ThisWorkbooks refers to the workbook which contains the code
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set uploader = Workbooks.Open(uploadfile, ReadOnly:=True) 'you can directly set the uploader workbook like this
    With uploader
        .Sheets("MySheet").UsedRange.Copy CurrentBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") 'change MySheet for the name of your working sheet
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Finds the proper path but after that when I select the file, It gives me the following error this time: Run-time error '1004': 'FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker).xlsx' could not be found... (I'm trying to open a .csv btw.).

Comment: @Willhelm true that! Edited my answer, tested and it works.

Comment: One more thing! I'm really sorry to trouble you.. It gives an error at .Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Copy CurrentBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") with "Out of range" error message. As the recently opened workbook's sheet name is variant. Thx!

Comment: @Willhelm is always the first sheet on the workbook? If so.. change the code for this: `.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy`